# Український відповідник до слова "топлес"

Tags: іменники, відповідник

В українській мові побутує слово "топлес", однак воно запозичене. Про нього читаємо у [Словнику іншомовних соціокультурних термінів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/39/53410/260975.html):

> **ТОПЛЕС** (від англ. topless - без верха) без верхньої частини одежі, з відкритими грудьми (про конкурсанток, моделей тощо).

Однак щось мене зацікавило, чи є власне український відповідник до цього слова, що відповідав би його семантиці.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/toples) знаходимо такі відповідники:

> **голіциць,  наголяса, головерхо, голоперса(ий), напівгольцем, голий торс, напівгола, голігрудь, голяка, безверхньо,  з голим верхом.**

Більша частина цих термінів мають явно розмовний відтінок: **наголяса, напівгольцем, голяка, голіциць**. *З голим верхом* вираз є нормативним , однак, цей варіант має найменше голосів ( очевидно через те, що складається з 2-х слів).